# Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject<{}>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm a beginner to Angular. I'm watching the tutorial of Mosh Hamedani using the Angular version 6 but the problem is the tutorial version is 4. I'm working on the e-commerce project on AddToCart button where the product should increase it's quantity by clicking the button and updated in Firebase using productId and also if I try to add new product then id of that new product should add in AngularFire Database.

Everything is working perfectly now I'm getting error in shopping-cart.service.ts file. The error is in the last line **async addToCart(product: Product)** where the error shows property pipe doesn't exist on type AngularFireObject.

Here is the code.

**shopping-cart.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Product } from '../models/products';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ShoppingCartService {
   constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

private create(){
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
        dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    })
}

private getCart(cartId: String){
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId);
}

private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string){
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
}

private async getOrCreateCartId(){
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
     if(cartId) return cartId;

    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;
}

async addToCart(product: Product){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);
    item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
        item$.update({ product: product, quantity:(item.quantity || 0) + 1 });
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I think in newer versions you should be using `valueChanges()` as observable: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md#retrieve-data

Answer (score 3):

the problem here is that your `this.getItem()` method isn't returning an `Observable`, instead it returns `AngularFireObject`, which hasn't `pipe` property, so you should call `valuChanges` method which will return an `Observable`

```
private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string){
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId).valueChanges();
}

async addToCart(product: Product){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);
    item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
        item$.update({ product: product, quantity:(item.quantity || 0) + 1 });
    });
}
```

Comment: Property 'update' does not exist on type 'Observable<AngularFireObject<{}>>' and  Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject<{}>'. this type of errors shows now.

Comment: ah sorry, I have updated my answer, please check again

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work same issue that i have mention in above comment. Still the update and quantity are underline as a error in VS code.

Comment: actually it shows error in vscode by underline the update and quantity which definitely cause error while compiling. Can you please suggest me how to fix this issue

Comment: there is no difference to use item$ and item to make just understandable i used item$ cause while subscribe I used item. Please let me know if you have better idea to solve this. Why this issue is underline by vscode.

Answer (score 2):

As the time of writing this answer, In AngularFireObject you have to use either `valueChanges()` or `snapshotChanges()`. You can read the [documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md)

Coming to your concern if you simply modify your code from

```
item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {})
```

to

```
item$.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {})
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

maybe instead of changing this line to 
        `return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId).valueChanges();`

leave it as it was 
`return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId)`
then in the function you are calling the getItem function before subscribing to it you can add value changes there 
should be something like

```
`private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string){
        return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
    }
 async addToCart(product: Product){
        let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
        let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key).valueChanges();
        item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
            item$.update({ product: product, quantity:(item.quantity || 0) + 1 });
        });
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
async  addToCart(product:Product){

  let cartId= await this.getOrCreateCart();
  let item$$=this.getItem(cartId,product.key);
  let item$=this.getItem(cartId,product.key).snapshotChanges();
    item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item=>{
      this.data=item.payload.val();

        if(this.data!= null){
          item$$.update({product:product,quantity:(this.data.quantity)+1});
        }else{
          item$$.set({product:product,quantity:1});
        }


    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make following changes in your code:

```
async addToCart(product: Product){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);
    item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
       item$.update({ product: product, 
                      quantity: (item.payload.exportVal().quantity || 0) + 1 });
    });
}
```

Just check-out my Github repository [My Github Link](https://github.com/Pranav50/E-Commerce) which is built in Angular 7. Your Angular 6 project will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

the best answer is incomplete in my opinion - just as @Sharad Sharma commented, this results in an error:

> Property 'update' does not exist on type
> 'Observable<AngularFireObject<{}>>' and Property 'quantity' does not
> exist on type 'AngularFireObject<{}>'. this type of errors shows now

To get rid of this error You need to type the object() function.
E.g
if Your '/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId node in firebase have two key/value pairs:

```
name: "test",
quantity: 1
```

Create an Object:

```
export class Product {
    name: string;
    quantity: number;

    constructor() {}
}
```

and then do this:

```
this.db.object<Product>('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId)...
```